# VBA Set printing format to created sheet

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to create a new sheet with no exact name just Sheetxx paste copied cells here, and then change printing format to fit all columns to one page. But    I am having troubles activate this new sheet because I don't know its name.

This is what I have now:

```
'
With Workbooks("Cards").Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")

   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ', False, False
   .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats ', False, False
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
   .FitToPagesWide = 1
   .FitToPagesTall = False
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

This code changes printing format on a sheet from which I copied cells.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: I can't see any code there to add a new sheet. The best way is to set a variable, e.g. `set ws=worksheets.add` and then reference ws.

Comment: First row of the code contains .Add and your modification worked thank you

Comment: Ah yes, I am having trouble reading today. @Mitch - agree it's good practice although when a sheet is added it is automatically activated.

Comment: I used ActiveSheet on purpouse because .Add method names the sheet Sheet1 or Sheet2 depenfing on the last Sheet , just now I modified it to save it as variable.

Comment: @SJR In my case it did not automatically activated the sheet that was the issue, but I guess it was not so clear from my description.

Comment: I don't understand how that can happen (or not happen in this case).

Comment: I have no idea but ActiveSheet command selected a completely different sheet.